# Is it possible to add right-click contextual menus to Windows 7 taskbar icons?

Tags: windows-7

I recently upgraded my workstation to Windows 7. The first thing I noticed is that when right-clicking my taskbar icons, I no longer get a contextual menu, just recent documents, unpin from taskbar and close application. An important part of my workflow is to be able to right click and application in the taskbar and choose an action from a plug-in allowing me to run the application as a different domain user. I can see this context menu option if I navigate to the start menu -> all programs, right click program, but I really would love that option in the taskbar. Is there any way to enable this functionality to override the default Windows 7 taskbar functionality? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 7 made it a little harder, right click on the taskbar icon, then right click again on the program icon will show 2 more options. It is not the full context menu, if you want that, hold the shift key down when right clicking on the taskbar icon.

[There is also tweaking software](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) for the taskbar if you don't like the defaults windows allows.

.

Right click twice,short context menu

[image: Right click twice]

.

Shift right click

[image]

Comment: Perfect, slows down my workflow just a tad, but for Windows 7, it's worth it. Thanks!